# Accessing of the data is not proper?

Tags: android

I am using android 2.1 platform.The code I have will display the Name number and email ID of all the persons from the Emulator contact list,by using this code I will get the requirement as on above.I have some contacts in my emulator, I created two more contacts (say C and D). BUT the issues are

**Issue 1.** If I create a new contact having **name and number not email**, This contact will take the   **email ID** from the contact just down to it.**for eg:** if I create a name C has no email ID but D has email ID, D is the contact already in the Emulator.  **C will take D's email ID**.C and D have same email ID.

**Issue 2.** If again I create a new contact having **name email but not number**, This contact will take the   **number** from the contact I previously created.**for eg:** if I create the name E has no number but it will take the number of the contact C. so **C and E have the same number** .

I am using this code

```
public class GetAllDatas extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvitems); 
    btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

    itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
    lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readContacts();
        }
    });

} 

private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            break;
        }
        emails.close();


        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                break;  
            } 
            pCur.close();
        }


        //  To display the Details
        contactlist.add(displayName+", "+phoneNumber+", "+ emailAddress+"\n");
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    cursor.close(); 
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i Understand your question..

Before add new item in reference variables just erase the previous one.. 
like,

```
emailAddress = "" ; 
displayName  = "" ;
phoneNumber  = "" ;
```

in your while loop for fetching contact information and adding it to list..

```
private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        emailAddress = "" ;
        displayName  = "" ;
        phoneNumber  = "" ;

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            break;
        }
        emails.close(); 
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                break;  
            } 
            pCur.close();
        }   

        //  To display the Details
        contactlist.add(displayName+", "+phoneNumber+", "+ emailAddress+"\n");          
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Just use the above readContacts()
method. (Replace it with yours) and let me know what happen..

Comment: tHANK YOU  user370305 I got the output what I expected, one thing is to do, one Contact having 2 numbers and 2 Email Id ( say name A have 2 num and 2 email)..Can you able to display it like     
A, firstNumber, firstEmail as the first row and   A, Second Number, Second Email  as the second row in listview 

is possible ?
This is the only problem now arise all others was gone.

Comment: Yes, It also possible, Just make logic in your for loop which check the display name at time of add contact number and email id if it already exist add new entry with same display name.

Answer (score 0):

try this one ..........

```
         public void readContacts(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
           null, null, null, null);

    contactName=new String[cur.getCount()];
   contactNumber=new String[cur.getCount()][];
   contactEmail=new String[cur.getCount()][];
   int i=0;
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
       while (cur.moveToNext()) {
           String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
           contactName[i]=name;
           Log.e("Contact Name",contactName[i]);
           if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {


               // get the phone number
               Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                      new String[]{id}, null);
               contactNumber[i]=new String[pCur.getCount()];
               int j=0;
               while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                contactNumber[i][j]=phone;
                Log.d("Contact number",contactNumber[i][j]);
                j++;
               }
               pCur.close();
           }
               // get email and type

              Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                       null,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                       new String[]{id}, null);
              contactEmail[i]=new String[emailCur.getCount()];
              int k=0;
               while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {

                   String email = emailCur.getString(
                                 emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                   String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                 emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                contactEmail[i][k]=email;
                Log.v("Contact email",contactEmail[i][k]);
                k++;
               }
               emailCur.close();


           }
       } i++;
  }
```